# How to redirect to page number? HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, numbers

this is what I currently have:

```
http://www.example.com/main?page=2
http://www.example.com/query?page=5
http://www.example.com/archives?page=2
```

And I want to replace it with:

```
http://www.example.com/main/2
http://www.example.com/query/5
http://www.example.com/archives/2
```

But I still want to have $_GET['page'] :)

How to do it with htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add these rules (preferably above any routing rules that you may have):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$ /$1?page=$2 [L]
```